# Music player which supports custom FLAC tags

Tags: music-player, flac

I'm reorganizing my music library and I'm hoping to use custom FLAC tags to better represent the contents of the files (most common tagging schemes work poorly for classical music, for example). Adding custom tags is simple using the "metaflac" package, but I've had trouble finding a music player that can actually handle such tags beyond a few "standard" ones like "Artist" or "Album" etc. Does such an application exist?

More specifically, the functionality I would like includes:

- Displaying custom tags during playback. Either simply showing all of them in a list or showing a customizable subset. So instead of just showing "Album"/"Artist"/"Title". It could also display user-defined "Conductor"/"Soloist" and other such tags.
- Being able to search within tags.
- I'd be extra happy if it was a terminal-application or something similarly lightweight.

I have experimented with [cmus](https://cmus.github.io/#home) and while it does support some "extended" tags such as "composer" it still only allows selection from a pre-baked list of tags, rather than being fully customizable.

Comment: Does FLAC even have a standard for tags? I thought any tags added (?) to FLAC files were always the player's custom format.

Comment: @muru I'm not super knowledgeable about the FLAC specification, but form what I understand your description is correct. My problem is that most music players have an assumed standard of tags which they will support and don't bother displaying/supporting anything else. Thus every program will automatically fetch and display the contents of the "Artist" tag; but won't show, for example, "Soloist".

Answer (score 0):

foobar2000 via wine allows the use of fully customizable tags.  I haven't found a suitable Linux-native substitute yet.  The only major problem I've had with it is that use of the Quick Search bar in a large library crashes the program.  This is unfortunate, because one of the major advantages to using custom tags in foobar2000 is the ability to integrate those tags into the Quick Search.  However, it still serves useful in customizing layout options and sorting/renaming/moving/etc. using those custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

I use Quod Libet, accepts any custom tag and displays tags on playback as you customize it.
And via

> **File ⇒ Plugin ⇒ Filter on any tag**

you can search tags as well. I believe there is a regex search plugin as well.
Tried sooo many players before I found this gem.

https://github.com/quodlibet/quodlibet

I believe Clementine can do it as well, just never liked it. Works on all platforms though.

https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine